# "Either x or either y-" why does this occur?

Tags: phrases, expressions, speech, either-or

Recently, I've noticed several instances of people repeating "either" in sentences, ex. "you're either the predator or you're either the prey." Is this a documented phenomenon, or am I just in odd company?

(I have heard this exclusively from monolingual English speakers- it seems similar to the Spanish use of "ni" but may or may not be related.)

Comment: The usual BrE, AmE, AuE etc dialects don't repeat "either" that way.

Comment: Native speakers have been known to make mistakes. A close relative frequently forgot to add the contrastive (the or-string).

Comment: You're in odd company.

Comment: I agree with the other comments.  Someone saying that would suggest to me that they are translating (incorrectly) from their own language.  Russian "либо ... либо".